# Linking grades to a quiz or dropbox in desire2learn

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I need to retrieve a unit's assessment items (with deep link, achievable score, and due date) via Valence API in desire2learn.

I am able to retrieve grades, calendars and dropboxes via the following API calls:

```
/d2l/api/le/1.2/{orgUnit}/grades/ 
/d2l/api/le/1.2/{orgUnit}/dropbox/folders/
/d2l/api/le/1.2/{orgUnit}/calendar/events/user/
```

I can see that the grades retrieved correspond to either a dropbox or a quiz (#grades = #quizzes + #dropboxes), and I can link a calendar item to a dropbox via 'associated entity id'.

I have also found that a calendar entry can be associated with an id of type 'D2L.LE.Quizzing.Quiz' but I don't know what to do with that ID.

It seems to me that I need to start with calendar entries which have an associated entity, then lookup either a dropbox or a quiz based on the association, and then match the dropbox or quiz to a grade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the API allows you to retrieve calendar events that associate to quiz entities, D2L does not yet have any APIs around the quiz entities themselves. You can retrieve the grade values/objects associated with a quiz, if the back-end service has associated grade items with the quiz; similarly, you can retrieve the calendar events associated with a quiz, as you have discovered. However, D2L doesn't yet provide a way to get at the quiz entity itself. This is an often-requested enhancement to the platform, and as a result, it does already exist on the product roadmap for future Learning Environment development; however, D2L does not yet have a committed release date for platform functionality around quiz entities.

Comment: Thanks for the update. As a sort-of workaround, I was able to link most grades to their corresponding calendar entries via the Name & Title fields (Grade.Name = Calendar.Title) and then to a dropbox by the calendar's AssociatedEntity. Having access to a quiz object, and being able to link a Grade to its corresponding Quiz or Dropbox would be great.